# TypeORM check decorator constraint with MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: mysql, typescript, mariadb, typeorm

I am new at using TypeORM and I want to use the check decorator for my MySQL/MariaDB database. After a few looks on the docs and on the Internet, I found that the check decorator was not implemented for MySQL. I'm stuck so I'm asking you if you knew any solution to work with a check constraint for my database in TypeORM.

For example, is there any way to implement the check decorator by myself? If so, how? I already looked at this question and the only solutions I found were for columns decorator, not entity (like here: [Typeorm Custom Decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555892/typeorm-custom-decorators))

Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet currently is to add the check constraint to your migrations by hand:

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD CONSTRAINT my_check CHECK (`my_col_a` XOR `my_col_b`)");
}

public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP CONSTRAINT my_check");
}
```

I have a comment in my code that says the functionality was merged into the typeorm repo and was waiting to be released, but I went back to look and couldn't find the PR so take that with a grain of salt.