# Typeorm: how to add a custom option to a column and get it from column metadata later?

Tags: node.js, orm, typeorm

I want to add a custom option **customOption**

```
@Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 150,
    unique: true,
    customOption: 'customValue'
})
name: string;
```

And then get it from column metadata

How to do this?

Comment: Could you describe, what problem you're trying to solve? Maybe there is a different or better approach to use while solving the problem? Generally, I won't recommend adjusting 3d party library structures with custom properties.

Comment: I need to save additional metadata in order to use it later. For instance I can postprocess this column or send all required information about a model to dynamically build user intеrface.

Comment: then you will probably need to attach this metadata in another way. It's not a good approach to mix your custom logic with the orm code.

Comment: @BlindKai I'm not going to mix my custom logic with the orm code. It sems to me that orm model is a good place to have all metadata together.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question, it's not possible to attach custom properties to the column or to specify one using `@Column` decorator options.

You can have a look at possible `@Column` options here in the documentation:
https://typeorm.io/entities#column-options

The only thing that comes to mind is that you could add a custom decorator and attach it to the corresponding metadata property. You can find more in this answer:
[TypeORM Custom Decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555892/typeorm-custom-decorators)